# Keyboard not found even though I'm including Keyboard.h

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I want to make a simple program to put on my Arduino/Genuino (Sunfounder) Uno board that when plugged in, it invokes the `Keyboard.print()` function.  When I compile my program to do that, it says that I'm not including `Keyboard.h` even though I actually am at the beginning of my program.

## My code:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
  Keyboard.begin();
  Keyboard.print("Hello, world!");
  Keyboard.end();
}


void loop() {

}
```

When I compile the code, I get this error:

`KeyboardMessage:4:3: error: 'Keyboard' not found. Does your sketch include the line '#include <Keyboard.h>'?`

I checked my libraries file in the Arduino sketch editor file and `Keyboard.h` is there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Keyboard.h not found " - that's not what the error message says.

Comment: Which version of Arduino and Keyboard do you use?

Comment: @ThomasSablik 1.8.7, 2.1

Comment: The newest version of keyboard I can find is 1.0.2. Where does your version come from?

Comment: @ThomasSablik wait, it's not 2.1, that's the version of the license; I can't find a version anywhere.  It's the version that comes with the IDE.

Comment: Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries. Search for Keyboard.

Comment: @ThomasSablik It's still giving me the same error even though I updated it to 1.0.2

Comment: @ThomasSablik an off-brand UNO R3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180588/discussion-between-thomas-sablik-and-coordinate-newton).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arduino/Genuino Uno does not support Keyboard. You can see it in `hardware/ardunino/avr/libraries/HID/HID.h`. This file is included from `Keyboard.h` and contains `#if defined(USBCON)`. But `USBCON` is not defined for Arduino/Genuino Uno. You need to use another board for `Keyboard.h`

Following controllers support it:

- ATmega32U6
- ATmega8U2
- ATmega16U2
- ATmega16U4
- ATmega32U2
- ATmega32U4
- and some ATxxUSBxx

Arduino/Genuino Uno uses ATmega32U8.

Answer (score -2):

You know what you don't require the `32u4` now, I got a solution to use keyboard and mouse through **any** Arduino.

All you have to do is something like this:

```
Serial.println("pressA")
```

**On the Arduino**

Head to a python script and do this:

```
import serial
import pyautogui
Arduino_Serial = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)

while 1:
    incoming_data = str(Arduino_Serial.readline())
    print(incoming_data)
    if 'pressA' in incoming_data:
        pyautogui.press('a')
    incoming_data = ""
```

Comment: So you gave to have a python script on the PC to send the serial input to the keyboard buffer. 
Not very compatible.